How to replicate an entire disk using ZFS
I have 2 x 2TB disks (they are not equal). In the master I have my ZFS pool (rpool, where Proxmox is installed in). I'd like to clone/replicate the entire disk on the slave once a day.
How can I do?

Do you really only want to do this once per day? It's a crappy way to do backups, and since ZFS replication only sends the delta there's no cost for doing it much more frequently.

In the master there are the real backups. I just want to make a copy of them. However, if there's no cost for doing it much more frequently I could do it every hour.

The answer are "zfs send" and "zfs receive" commands.
In your case may looking like:
root@master #> zfs send .... | ssh root@slave zfs receive ...
there are several options for full and incremental, see man zfs-send and zfs-receive.
